# React - UseEffect hook with Redux store in dependency array and which updates the state ends in an endless loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux

I have an array of certain objects in my redux store and I retrieve it like so:

`const storeExpenses = useSelector(({ expenses }: RootState) => expenses.items));`

I then save those expense objects also in the components local state since I have to further filter them without wanting to change them in the store.

`const [expenses, setExpensesInState] = useState<Expense[]>(storeExpenses);`

Now, when my store expenses are updated somewhere else, I want to refresh the local state as well, like so:

```
useEffect(() => {
   setExpensesInState(storeExpenses));
}, [storeExpenses]);
```

However this results in an endless loop of the useEffect hook.

My assumption is that when I use setExpensesInState, I trigger a redraw of the component which then sets the expensesInStore variable which in turn triggers again the useEffect and so on. Is this assumption correct or am I misunderstanding anything else? And how would I resolve this to achieve what I need?

Comment: Yes you are effectively creating a recursive loop. I don't have an answer to the problem which is why I have only wrote a comment. To solve your problem in it's current state you would have to have a conditional if statement within useEffect().

Comment: Try creating a clone of `storeExpenses` as your initial state - this way you won't change the original value and prevent the infinite loop. In general it's preferable to not mutate original values, for this reason

Comment: Can you post the full code for this component?  The snippet you posted, standing alone, should not cause a loop. I’m wondering if you have code elsewhere that is setting the value of storeExpenses based on expenses.